# How to add docs to gradle plugin extension variables?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, gradle-plugin

Okay, let's make this question as simple as possible.

I am trying to build a Gradle plugin. I have an extension named `MyExt`.

```kotlin
open class MyExt {

    /**
     * <p>This is some sample docs</p>
     */
    var myVar: String = "myVar is awesome"
}
```

and this is my plugin

```kotlin
class MyAwesomePlugin : Plugin<Project> {


    override fun apply(project: Project) {

        val myExt : MyExt = project.extensions.create("my-awesome-plugin", MyExt::class.java)

        ...
    }

}
```

and when I try to implement this plugin in a project, the IntelliJ is not showing docs for `myVar` as it shows for other Gradle variables.

**Not showing for myVar**

[image]

**But showing for Gradle variables**

[image]

I've both `sources` and `docs` jar in my repo.

- Why it's not showing the variable doc? What am I missing?
- How to add docs to the extension variables in a Gradle plugin?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; It's a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-241835)

1. Make sure you have correct documentation format: refer to [Documenting Kotlin Code](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html) E.g. for me it works with this comment:

```
/**
* This is some sample docs
*/
```

Also make sure you have applied the plugin and re-imported Gradle project:

[image]

Comment: Alright. Can you send that sample project to me? I just want to make sure that my IDE works as yours.

Comment: I've done same as yours. The docs are in good format and reimported the project, still negative. Can you send that project to theapache64@gmail.com

Comment: Please provide a sample project to check.

Comment: I can see you're using the `buildSrc` method, but in my case it's a `Standalone project`. I've tried the `buildSrc` method, and it works fine. But it's not working when I access the plugin using maven repo. Here's the [sample project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T17dmEP18wx_naNQs7umvyUf36W9Hq5o/view?usp=sharing). Please follow the README before building.

Comment: The project is empty.

Comment: It must have a README file.It's the instruction to setup the project.Once you finish setup,you'll see sources.  (README TLDR: as it's a maven project, you've to first run the `install` task to deploy it to localMaven to be used it in the sample project)

Comment: Indeed it is not supported in plugin is installed in local maven repository. Please vote for this issue: [IDEA-241835](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-241835)

Comment: FTR: the provided project did not contain any source or build gradle files. I've reproduced it in my own project.

Comment: Thank you reporting the issue. I've upvoted it. Btw, here is a [screen record](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GGEBC_wIkzfck2YIAHNrX11KEj2bIgPW) on how to build the project. Can you confirm that's how you did?